# Dropzone and webpack encore

Tags: symfony4, dropzone, webpack-encore

I'm trying and integration of dropzone in my Symfony 4.1 project, but I'm in trouble.

I add dropzone to my project via npm: `npm install dropzone`.

In *assets/app.js*, I require dropzone:

```
'use strict';

require('../css/app.css');

// create global $ and jQuery variables
import('jquery');

require('bootstrap');

require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css');
require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js');
require('dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.js');

require('./main.js');  // assets/js/main.js
```

In *main.js*, I just try to add that function:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
```

As soon as I try to make some configuration for dropzone, my browser console is going crazy: Dropzone is not defined.

I'm asking myself what's wrong here.

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing that `window.Dropzone = require('dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min');`

I had the problem some months ago, and if I remember correctly, that's what did the trick for me.

In my case, I have a `dropzone.js` that `require` Dropzone css/js, and my file `dropzone-upload.js`.
Then in my `dropzone-upload.js` I can use `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` just fine.

In my webPack, I `addEntry` for my `dropzone.js` file.

```
    ...
    //file upload with dropzone
    .addEntry('dropzone', './assets/js/dropzone.js')
    ...
```

Comment: So mister @Etshy... Thank you very much!

I just add `window.Dropzone = require('dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min');` in my main.js, and I don't have issue anymore.

I admit... All this webpac-encore make me confuse sometimes :/