# Why Symfony UX (Dropzone) packages don't include JS scripts?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, dropzone.js, webpack-encore

I'm currently testing the new [Symfony UX Dropzone](https://github.com/symfony/ux-dropzone) and after a few hours of research I still have one question left to answer: Why don't UX packages include JS scripts? - **how is Symfony supposed to include `dropzone(.min).js` for example ?**

Currently for the code to work I have to:

1. Download the `dropzone.js` file from the official website.
2. Place the file under `/assets/dropzone/dropzone.js`
3. Add to the `assets/app.js` file the line `window.Dropzone = require('./dropzone/dist/dropzone.js');`

I started by creating a new project and then installing Dropzone as follows:

```shell
symfony composer req ux-dropzone
npm install
npm run build
```

`/src/Form/FormType.php`

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('file', DropzoneType::class)
    ;
}
```

`/src/templates/base.html.twig`

```twig
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

`/assets/app.js`

```twig
import './styles/app.css';

window.Dropzone = require('./dropzone/dropzone.js');

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';
```

Without this manual import of the `dropzone(.min).js` file the variable `window.Dropzone` is not initialized.

I found a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129017/dropzone-and-webpack-encore), however it seems that in this case the installation of the package created the file `/node_modules/ux-dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.js`. But in my case here is the generated tree structure:

[image: tree structure]

Is this the right way to proceed?

Wishing you a good day :)

Comment: I haven't gone through UX yet, but I'd assume it would come in through `yarn` or `npm` and be stored in the node_modules folder. Is it not?

Comment: That's what I assumed too but it seems that only two js files are imported into `/nodes_modules/@symfony/ux-dropzone` named `dist/controller.js` and `src/controller.js` -  there is no trace of `dropzone.js`... "tree structure" link in my previous position shows the tree structure of the folder

Comment: Hi, have you found anything since then ? I am also struggling to make it work. I have the UI, but it isn't responding when I upload files...

Comment: `window.Dropzone = require('./dropzone/dropzone.js');` is not necessary.